# How to set days between 4pm - 4pm CST instead of 24hrs SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Just need a little help with a query I'm working on. Our data currently is calculating at our local CST time. But I need to make a new view with a new change, where our day instead of being between 12am to 11:59pm, it should now be from 4pm yesterday to 4pm today. So today being Sunday, Saturday reporting should be between 4pm Friday to 4pm Saturday. How can I write that in sql server? I did find some related questions on this here, but nothing specific to my need. Any help would be great!

I've created this query which shows data for the day from 12am to 4pm, but I need the day to be from yesterday 4pm to today 4pm. How would I create a new day based off this time frame?

```
WHERE ALLOC_DATE >= DATEADD(HOUR, -8, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, ALLOC_DATE) AS DATE) 
AS DATETIME)) 
AND 
ALLOC_DATE < DATEADD(HOUR, 16 , CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 0, ALLOC_DATE) AS DATE) 
AS DATETIME))
```

Comment: What is your difficulty? Adding a time component to a date value?

Comment: yes that. Not sure how to add that to a date value that will pick up yesterday from 4pm + today till 4pm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). It will allows you to adjust your current time.

For example,

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, -32, CAST('2020-11-22 00:00:00' AS DATETIME2(0))) AS [date_beg]
      ,DATEADD(HOUR, -32, CAST('2020-11-23 00:00:00' AS DATETIME2(0))) AS [date_end];
```

Comment: Thanks! that helps. Now how would I go about assigning my days according to this new date? So Sunday has to be between saturday 4pm to sunday 4pm.